# Amazon SNS publishing to Topic feedback

Tags: android, iphone, amazon-web-services, notifications, push

I am currently using Amazon SNS to publish push notifications to both Androids and iPhone devices using Topics.

I am having trouble in the scenario where if the APNS certificate is invalid, the Topic Publishing API does not provide any feedback or errors.

Hope someone have a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer in the Amazon forum - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=587138#587138

Simply create a new topic and set the EventDeliveryFailure to this topic and you'll be notified if anything goes wrong!